# Android , a progress like Android Boot?

Tags: android, shader, progress

I have to create a progress that looks like Android Boot Progress:

[image]

I guess that It can be done by overriding `onDraw()` method of `TextView` and repaint it through a thread.But is it possible?And is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) example. There are lots of examples in a single tutorial / app which might give you guidelines.

Comment: I do not see any pattern there which looks like what I need.